# Function canWeMakeIt(myWord, myLetters) always returns False

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

> `canWeMakeIt(myWord, myLetters)` - return `True` or `False`.
>
> Write a function which answers the question: Can I form the word `myWord` from the string of letters `myLetters`?
>
> The function should return a boolean `True` or `False`. Converting `myLetters` to a list and using the `pop()` or `remove()` method may come in handy.

This is what I have:

```
def canWeMakeIt(myWord, myLetters):
    canMake= True
    myLettersList= list(myLetters)
    length=len(myWord)
    for k in range(length):
        for i in range(0,k):
            i=i+1
            letter=myWord[i]
            if myWord[i] not in myLettersList:
                canMake= False
            else:
                myLettersList.remove(myWord[i])
    return canMake
```

but it is returning false for everything. :(

Comment: please add a proper language tag

Comment: Please format your code (using Ctrl K) and add the programming language a tag.

Comment: Add an example of correct and wrong input.

Answer (score 1):

the way you're thinking about it is correct, you just made a little mistake:
you only need one for-loop, just to go through the letters of the word.

```
def canWeMakeIt(myWord, myLetters):

canMake= True
myLettersList= list(myLetters)
length=len(myWord)

for i in range(length): 
 i=i+1 
 letter=myWord[i] 
 if letter not in myLettersList:
  canMake= False 
 else: 
  myLettersList.remove(letter) 

return canMake
```

PS: you created the **letter** variable but you didn't use it